# $http angularjs php response

Tags: php, angularjs, json, http

Quite new to angularjs, but already done some research.
I'm making the following $http post request:

```
       $scope.onClick2 = function () {
            var myRequest = {};
            myRequest = {};
            myRequest.ServiceType = "SearchExams";
            myRequest.SessionId = 'SessionlessRequest';
            myRequest.Compression = 'no';
            myRequest.Parameters = {};
            myRequest.Parameters.Status = ['30', '40'];
            myRequest = JSON.stringify(myRequest);
            var request = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/request.php',
                data: 'data=' + myRequest,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            })
        };
```

My request.php handles the request and sends back an json response.
Howerver I see in the response tab of chrome and in fiddler that the original request is also in the response. See below:

```
Array
(
[data] => {"ServiceType":"SearchExams","SessionId":"SessionlessRequest","Compression":"no","Parameters":{"Status":["30","40"]}}
)
{"Error":false,"ErrorMessage":null,"Data":[{"ExamID":1,"A.......
```

I would expect only the last line ({"Error":false,"ErrorMessage":null,"Data":[{"ExamID":1,"A...... to be returned....looking at what my request.php send back it should.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Comment: And where is your PHP code? We cant tell from your JS why PHP is returning something different

Comment: This part is from my PHP code,
Logger::LogDebug("response: $response");
And this part is in the logging.:
2016-01-19 14:44:09 - DEBUG --> [::1][] [Request] response: {"Error":false,"ErrorMessage":null,"Data":[{"ExamID":1,".....

Comment: Remove logging obviously, print_r or whatever you are using in controller

Comment: Sorry dfsq, I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry guys, already fixed it myself, I indeed had an error in my php code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for waisting anybodies time on this.
There was an error in my php code indeed.